# Is there any way to change url in Laravel 5.5?

Tags: php, laravel, url

I am developing a site with Laravel 5.5

I am going to hide the product slug when customers visit single product page.

original url: http://localhost/laravel/product/category-name-product-slug (this is product slug in database)

must be changed to: http://localhost/laravel/product/category-name.php (or html)

The problem is that I have to send the product-slug to controller so that know about what product is needed instead of product ID.

Also I have to show category name(this must be substring of product-slug: substr($product_name, 0, -10)) on browser url.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: I tried to solve this using Route::get(\Illuminate\Support\Str::substr("item/{slug}", 0, -10),'Front\CatalogController@product')->name('front.product'); in route, but it is not working for {slug}. But if I try for "item", it works.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have solved this problem by using form.

I have created a form in blade and made its method to POST.

Defined a hidden variable to represents product slug, and then render a virtual slug name (substring of product slug) to route.

Comment: How do you populate the hidden variable if it's not in the URL of this page already?

Answer (score 0):

If you can't put it in the path you'll have to use a query string.

[Retrieving Input From The Query String](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/requests#retrieving-input)

```
e.g. http://localhost/laravel/product/category-name.php?product-slug=product-slug
```

and if you have to do that you might not lose any seo by also passing the category and product ids in the query string.

Comment: Hi @coedycode. As I mentioned earlier, I can't show the slug on the url

Comment: You have to pass something through the url, how else could the controller know which product to show? Unless you do something with cookies or session so that different users get a different product shown on the same url.

Comment: It's not quite clear why you don't want to show the slug. Is it for security reasons? There's no way to retrieve the item if you have no reference to it whatsover, that's just not possible.

If you can't show the slug for security reasons, hash it?

Comment: Unless every category only has exactly 1 product, then you have to identify the product in the url, by slug, id, or hash. Google isn't going to have a cookie or session when it spiders, so how would you know which product to show google if you're not identifying it via the url?

Comment: I can't know. It was my client's requirement. I have done this with input hidden variable. By post method, the hidden variable will be sent to controller and in route, the slug is shown substring of slug.